# Estimating the dof for t test of Correlation Coefficients of smoothed time courses

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, cross-correlation

I'm working with an array of size 265 x 5000.
Each column is a time series and the rows are points in a series of volumes
( voxels in fMRI ).

I preprocessed this data in several ways, most of which have some sort of filtering mechanism.

My task is to compute the correlation coefficient between all voxels, compute a T test, find the p values and correct my coefficients for values above a threshold. Then there's more steps, but they are not relevant as far as I know.

I know how to compute the T test of the corr coefs, but unclear on the DOF.

```
import numpy as np
# roi is my variable holding the 265 x 5000 data
corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(roi.T)# transpose of roi
corr.shape
>>>(5000,5000) # to be clear in case I messed up somewhere...
```

Thinking this might be helpful, I computed the rank of the corr array with:

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(corr)
>>>225
```

The rank of the time series array:

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(roi.T) # the transpose
>>>236
```

I don't really know what I'm doing here and hoping there's a clear way of
estimating the dof of this array.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I feel kinda dumb having computed rank. Neither matrix is a system of linear equations...so that probably made no sense...I think what I was after, is
something akin to computing the eigen values of the cross correlation array.

I've read in a genetic research paper dealing with large cross correlation matrices, that a fractional eigen value means there's dependence and integer's are independent. So that e.v. = 1.45 would mean 1 independent and 0.45 of another independent e.value. I haven't been able to confirm this.

UPDATE:
Maybe I wasn't wrong to compute the rank of the roi above. Since each col is a vector,if there are scalars a and b, which result in  a*c_1 + b*c_2 = 0, then c_1 and c_2 are dependent.

If roi has rank 236, then corr has dof = 236**2 ....?

Comment: Is this a novel problem in the stats community...? Perhaps I'll try the EE people. Not sure how to migrate the thread but will attempt it. Thanks for reading even if you didn't have a solution. :)

Comment: It doesn't look novel to me, but it's really hard to tell from your description. Normally one wouldn't see t-tests and screening by p-values performed between time series: there are very few kinds of time series data for which these procedures would be appropriate and even fewer temporo-spatial datasets like this one. I believe you would get better information out of this community by editing your question to focus more on the nature of your data and on what information you need to get from them.

Comment: In the fMRI field, which is new to me, I understand this to be a standard analysis. I have time series and I want to know the dependence between them bc it relates one region to another.

Comment: That's what's so confusing: t-tests don't say anything at all about dependence.  If you're trying to describe a standard procedure, it would help your readers understand your question better if you could provide an accessible reference to it.

Comment: The SNR is poor and is directly prop to the corr coef. Also, I want to know which corr coef are distinctly different from my H0 ( H0=0 is common or I like H0=mu ).

Comment: Thanks whuber, I will attempt a better explanation with ref to literature.